# Visitor pattern accepting a strategy - is there any gain?

Tags: strategy-pattern, visitor-pattern

I have been using the Visitor pattern for a payment system in my application. I have 10 payment types (paypal, banktransfer, stripe, omise, etc). but once i made it i was wondering the point of visitor pattern when i could use a strategy pattern.  Let me show you what i have created so far:

```
class PaymentGetCreditCardsVisitor(var presenter: MyPresenter, var usersAddress: AddressModel) : IVisitor {
    override fun visit(strategy: PaymentStrategy) { //notice how its accepting a strategy !!!!!
        strategy.fetchCreditCards(presenter, addressModel) //gets the cards for this payment type
    }
}


interface IVisitor {
   //list out all the classes the visitor can visit now
   fun visit(strategy: PaymentStrategy)
}

interface IVisitable {
    fun accept(v: IVisitor)
}
```

in code i have a factory that gets me back the payment strategy depending on users country:

```
class PaymentStrategyFactory  constructor(private var payByOmiseStrategy: PayByOmiseStrategyStrategy,
 private var payByBankTransferPaymentStrategy: PayByBankTransferPaymentStrategy, etc, etc,etc,etc) {

    fun getPaymentStrategy(country: String): PaymentStrategy {
        return when (country) {
            "china" -> payByOmiseStrategy
            "somalia" -> payByBankTransferPaymentStrategy.get()
            }
            }
}
```

all thats happening above is its a factory that is returning a payment strategy depending on some type i pass in which is predetermined.  so if the country is china i use omise and if its some small island i'll use bank transfer, etc.

here is how one strategy might look:

```
            interface PaymentStrategy {
         fun fetchCreditCards(presenter: MyPresenter,address: AddressModel);
}

and its implementation:

         class PayByOmiseInternetBankingPaymentStrategy  : PaymentStrategy {

         fun fetchCreditCards(presenter: MyPresenter,address: AddressModel){
//do some work and get thte credit cards for the omise card strategy
         }

}
```

Now lets talk about my concern. here is how i actually call the visitor to do the work:

```
PaymentStrategy strategy = (PaymentStrategy) mPaymentStrategyFactory.getPaymentStrategy("china");
        new PaymentGetCreditCardsVisitor(presenter, address).visit(strategy);

    and the work gets done.  

    but could i not have also called it like this:

    `strategy.fetchCreditCards(presenter, addressModel)` and not used a visitor at all ?  
    What are the benefits to using a visitor pattern then when i can do the same thing with a strategy ? should i be combining them like this ? is it more scalable ? the language is in kotlin but im more concerned about the implementation details of the patterns and its usage. IM concerned that my visitor is taking in a strategy to invoke ? is this not a wrapper ontop of another wrapper ? i want to know the benefits of it.
```